# Support for .aspx in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

In 2013 this question was asked. There were hints that ReSharper results could be viewed within SonarQube in a future version.  I have checked the pages for C#, VB.NET and have not found a plugin at this time that allows adding .aspx files to a SonarQube project.

Has there been any traction on this topic, or a general effort to support reporting on issues noted with ReSharper on file types like .aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This use case is still not supported.

There now is a way in SonarQube to import all types of files, regardless of whether or not it corresponds to an installed language plugin.

But even if you did that, R# issues will not be imported on it - because we check that the file language matches either C# or VB.NET explicitly: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-resharper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/resharper/ReSharperSensor.java#L146

I've created the following ticket, but doubt that it will be fixed soon: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARRSHPR-19